# How to use json in javascript if encoded data is undetermined

Tags: javascript, php, database

I'm trying to create a function for my website that allows a user to log in, then accesses their specific data from a database (PHP), then displays their user data on a screen in html. I know I have to encode the PHP data using json_encode, then use json_parse in javascript. The problem I'm having is that all tutorials for the javascript portion look like this:

```
var text = '{ "name":"John", "birth":"1986-12-14", "city":"New York"}';
var obj = JSON.parse(text);
```

but I can't enter what data I want to call specifically because it changes for each user, all I have is the column. The encoded data in PHP looks like this:

```
echo json_encode($_SESSION['currentlevel']);
```

But I don't know what to put in the javascript to call the encoded data I need.

I can't use php in the javascript file.

Right now this is my PHP:

```
<?php
session_start();

$link = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);

$sql = "SELECT CurrentLevel FROM UserInfo1 WHERE 
UserEmail = '". mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_SESSION['useremail']) . 
"'";

$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

if (!$result) {
die(mysqli_error());
}

$_SESSION['currentlevel'] = '{"CurrentLevel": "'.$result.'"}';

if (!$_SESSION['currentlevel']) {
die(mysqli_error());
}

    echo json_encode($_SESSION['currentlevel']);
```

And my Javascript looks like this:

```
function getcurrentlevel() {
var xmlhttp, myObj;
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    document.getElementById("CurrentLevel").innerHTML = " Level: 'myobj'";
    }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", "php5.php", true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: Two options: 1. you dynamically create an additional javascript file by means of php. That way you _can_ encode the payload in the javascript source. 2. you use javascript to make an initial loading ajax request to the server which is responded to by a php script which sends the payload.

Comment: What would the code for the second option look like? How is that different from what I have?

Comment: So the user is logged in, right? And the the site you are accessing the PHP from is on the same domain?  So when the user enters your html-site you want JS to fetch this information? Then you don't have to send anything: the `$_SESSION` should be set in the `.php` script since the session cookie is sent with the `XMLHttpRequest`.

Comment: Will the PHP variable work in javascript? I figured it wouldn't call since the program I use doesn't let me put <?php ?> tags in the javascript file. How does the program know to call the encoded json I need? @AndreasStorvikStrauman

Comment: No, not unless you ask `PHP` to parse the javascript. The reason you want to add something is so `PHP` knows which user is communicating with the server, right? As long as there is a session cookie set, i.e. you have used `$_SESSION['something']`, the session variable is available in PHP, also when JS is the client.

Comment: I still don't fully understand how to call the data I need in Javascript. When I put $_SESSION[] in the JS file it doesn't do anything. The JS file is separate from the PHP file. Sorry if my questions are dumb I'm completely new to all of this. What specifically do I need to change about my code or write in order to get the value of the session variable in JS? @AndreasStorvikStrauman

Comment: Your user logs in, and you create, say,`$_SESSION['username']="Mekade"`. The user then goes to some site `overview.php`. This site provides some html and some javascript, where the javascript is responsible for loading some content from the PHP. This is what you're trying to achieve, correct? Now. The `XMLHttpRequest` is sending asynchronous request to the php script. The `onreadystatechange` is what to do when the request finished. So the request is sent to php, where you still have access to `$_SESSION['username']`, and that could be sent back as JSON. You can't do `$_SESSION` in javascript.

Comment: Thanks for your patience. I understand the principles behind what I need to do, the code I'm writing just isn't working. Right now I have the updated code in question. The problem I'm having is getting the code to do what I need it to. @AndreasStorvikStrauman

Comment: I've been in your shoes at some point, and I feel your frustration! I'll write you an answer.

Comment: Actually, there is an answer already: @ptica beat me to it.

Comment: @Mekade24: Just to ask the obvious questions: is the filename of the php you're trying to load called `php5.php`?

Comment: Maybe you could use developer tools and show us what the request headers and responses are?

Answer (score 2):

at least two details have to be corrected in your current approach:

(i) in the php5.php file:

```
$_SESSION['currentlevel'] = '{"CurrentLevel": "'.$result.'"}';
```

the right hand side is already valid stringified json (you produced it by string concatenation which is ok. another option with same effect would be

```
$_SESSION['currentlevel'] = json_encode(array('CurrentLevel' => $result));
```

(ii) on the js side you need to actually use the returned value like this:

```
document.getElementById("CurrentLevel").innerHTML = " Level: " + myObj.CurrentLevel;
```

Comment: I really wish I could say this worked... there has to be something inherently wrong with another page of my code because otherwise I cant explain why this seemingly simple action has taken me over a week to figure out even with all of the resources I can find on the internet. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

a simpler option would be to do not include the example code:

```
var text = '{ "name":"John", "birth":"1986-12-14", "city":"New York"}';
var obj = JSON.parse(text);
```

in a .js file but to include it into a `<script>` tag into a `<header>` of a file that you generate by PHP - that way you may variate the content of the text var, like this

```
<header>
  <script>
    var obj = { "name": "<?= $name ?>" };
  <script>
</header>
```

ie the JS code is dynamically prepared by PHP with values you need there, and thats all you need